# Using replace sql function in nHibernate named query

Tags: .net, nhibernate, named-query, sql-function

I am using Nhibernate 2.1.0 in my project.

I have the an Item class with property Path and the following named query:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns='urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'>
     <sql-query name='updateUNC'>
    <query-param name='oldUNC' type='String'/>
    <query-param name='newUNC' type='String'/>
    <![CDATA[
       update Item s set
          s.Path= replace(s.Path,:oldUNC, :newUNC),
    ]]>
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I execute the named query using the following code:

```
session.GetNamedQuery("updateUNC")
       .SetString("oldUNC", "old")
       .SetString("newUNC", "new")
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

But I get the following exception:

```
 NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException was unhandled
   Message="Can't determine SqlType of parameter name=oldUNC, expectedType=Unknow\n      Possible cause: wrong case-sensitive property-name."
   Source="NHibernate"
   StackTrace:
        at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Exec.BasicExecutor.Execute(QueryParameters parameters, ISessionImplementor session) in C:\Projects\Nhibernate\nhibernate2.1.0\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\Exec\BasicExecutor.cs:line 66
        at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.ExecuteUpdate(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session) in C:\Projects\Nhibernate\nhibernate2.1.0\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:line 149
        at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan.PerformExecuteUpdate(QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session) in C:\Projects\Nhibernate\nhibernate2.1.0\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLQueryPlan.cs:line 328
        at NHibernate.Impl.StatelessSessionImpl.ExecuteUpdate(String query, QueryParameters queryParameters) in C:\Projects\Nhibernate\nhibernate2.1.0\src\NHibernate\Impl\StatelessSessionImpl.cs:line 962
        at NHibernate.Impl.QueryImpl.ExecuteUpdate() in C:\Projects\Nhibernate\nhibernate2.1.0\src\NHibernate\Impl\QueryImpl.cs:line 120
        at Catalog.Repository.ItemsRepository.ChangeUNC(String oldUNC, String newUNC) in C:\Projects\Catalog\Catalog\Repository\ItemsRepository.cs:line 148
```

I also tried setting the parameter value using SetParameter<string> and SetParameter(":oldUNC", "old" NHibernateUtil.String) but it also failed with the same error. It is like NHibernate just ignore me saying thet teh parameter value is string :(.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Did you try to write string with lower case in the mapping file?

```
<query-param name='oldUNC' type='string'/>
```